# Why is the value returned from a ConcurrentDictionary always null when multiple concurrent threads are used?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

I've implemented a simple memory cache backed by the ConcurrentDictionary

```
public class MemoryCache 
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheObject> _memory;

    public MemoryCache()
    {
        this._memory = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, CacheObject>();
    }


    private bool TryGetValue(string key, out CacheObject entry)
    {
        return this._memory.TryGetValue(key, out entry);
    }

    private bool CacheAdd(string key, object value, DateTime? expiresAt = null)
    {
        CacheObject entry;
        if (this.TryGetValue(key, out entry)) return false;

        entry = new CacheObject(value, expiresAt);
        this.Set(key, entry);

        return true;

    }

    public object Get(string key)
    {
        long lastModifiedTicks;
        return Get(key, out lastModifiedTicks);
    }

    public object Get(string key, out long lastModifiedTicks)
    {
        lastModifiedTicks = 0;
        CacheObject CacheObject;
        if (this._memory.TryGetValue(key, out CacheObject))
        {
            if (CacheObject.HasExpired)
            {
                this._memory.TryRemove(key, out CacheObject);
                return null;
            }
            lastModifiedTicks = CacheObject.LastModifiedTicks;
            return CacheObject.Value;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        var value = Get(key);
        if (value != null) return (T)value;
        return default(T);
    }


    public bool Add<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        return CacheAdd(key, value);
    }
}
```

and now I'm trying to test it with code that is based off of a [blog post](https://ayende.com/blog/4802) from @ayende.

```
var w = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var threads = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
{
    threads.Add(new Thread(() =>
    {
        w.WaitOne();
        DoWork(i);
    }));
    threads.Last().Start();
}

w.Set();//release all threads to start at the same time
foreach (var thread in threads)
{
    thread.Join();
}
```

So DoWork calls a process that contains the singleton cache manager and in my case it's going off and authenticating from a system and returns a token. This token is then stored with a unique key (user name). Now each of these calls, in my case there are 8 cores/threads the user name is the same, let's say "BobUser:CacheKey".

Everytime I run the code I see that 8 requests are being made because the cache Get always returns null.

```
var token = _cm.Cache.Get<MyToken>(userId);
if (token != null) return token;
token = base.Logon(userId, password);
if (token != null)
{
    _cm.Cache.Add(userId, token);
}
return token;
```

Is this really because of the 8 threads interacting Exactly at the same time? If that is the case, is there a pattern to fix this concurrency issue?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because in order for the cache to kick in, at least one thread would have to completely finish authenticating, and adding to the cache, before other threads even get to the `.Get()` call at the top.

```
var token = _cm.Cache.Get<MyToken>(userId); // <-------------------------------+
if (token != null) return token;            //                                 |
token = base.Logon(userId, password);       //                                 |
if (token != null)                          //                                 |
{                                           //                                 |
    _cm.Cache.Add(userId, token); //<-- A thread needs to execute this before  |
                                  // other threads even execute this  ----------
}
return token;
```

You make things worse by blocking threads and starting them at the approximately same time. If you want to fix it, put a `lock` around your authentication, so that only one authentication request goes out at a time.

An example might look like this:

```
private static object AuthenticationLocker = new object();
private string GetToken(string userId)
{
    lock (AuthenticationLocker)
    {
        var token = _cm.Cache.Get<MyToken>(userId);
        if (token != null) return token;
        token = base.Logon(userId, password);
        if (token != null)
        {
            _cm.Cache.Add(userId, token);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Note that if you do start using locks, you can use a regular cache, rather than a thread-safe cache.

If you don't want to use locks, then you need to accept the fact that you may have multiple requests dispatching at the same time. You can't have it both ways

Comment: I've exacerbated the issue with the multi threaded test harness on purpose. This code will live in an ASP.NET/WCF host where it 'should' perform well enough. My solution during testing is to prime the test before hand with one request that has no contention, thus making it all the way through.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the section [So how does ConcurrentDictionary do better?](https://arbel.net/2013/02/03/best-practices-for-using-concurrentdictionary/)

The reads do not have locks, so if they all try to read before data is actually there they will all receive null.